# Multi location pages for local SEO

Tags: website-design, interaction-design, user-expectation, marketing

I'm building a website for a client and they have one business address but work within all of the surrounding towns and villages. I wanted to create a specific page for each one of these locations with unique content to help personalise and benefit the person who lives in that town or village when searching the website.

Each one of these pages should have an address and a google map to help with local SEO but with only one business address i don't want to start duplicating content making it look like I'm trying to manipulate the search results.

So:

- Should I just avoid the address on each page and just use each location as way to highlight the benefits this company can bring in order to help with organic search?
- or should I just have one page that mentions all of these other locations plus all the benefits?

As far as UX is concerned I believe it would be better if each area had its own unique page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We work with a couple companies with the same setup, and what we do is to create a page for each different location, with its own address, phone, service description, reviews and photos.

Then take advantage of [**structured data**](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data) and [**rich snippets**](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2009/05/introducing-rich-snippets.html) to provide the most accurate information, and so far Google likes these pages a lot. We also use Google's highlighting tool for this purpose and the results are outstanding.

In short: **yes, create a page for each location** (and don't forget a location's index!)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, and sorry for making you repeat yourself. But as they only have one psychical address; should I still place that address on each location page, even if I have about six to create?

Comment: Ah, ok, I misunderstood the question. In this case, while you don't need necessarily different addresses, you'll need to ponder and asses if the information you addd for each location has value. If that's not the case, then use only one page and then explain *"we serve location 1, location 2, location n"*

Comment: It's fine, I've learnt loads from your reply.  Its for a taxi firm that works in areas who have large hotels for celeb's and people on business/events where they often need a taxi for airport journeys or to the local train station that has direct roots to London. Also, there are a few large festivals / supper markets, plus things like public transport within the local areas no longer run like they once did, plus many more local events, etc, etc!!! So maybe the question now is should I create a page for Festivals, a page for Hotels, etc. and not create a new page for each town or village name.

Comment: YES! That's the correct approach, and then you can use what I mentioned in my answer, but this time you can use, instead of "Local Businesses", "Events" (for festivals), if you have "Services", then use the "Service" schema and so on :)

Comment: Awesome and thank you ever so much for your time. :)